# Azure service bus queue Message deadlettered after Message.Abandon

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying out Azure Service Bus queue. I have the below code:

Queue send:

```
string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"];
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(strConnectionString);
        if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists("Test"))
        {
            QueueDescription qD = new QueueDescription("Test");
            qD.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = new TimeSpan(05, 00, 00);
            qD.LockDuration = new TimeSpan(00, 02, 30);
            qD.MaxSizeInMegabytes = 5120;                
            namespaceManager.CreateQueue(qD);              
        }
        if (namespaceManager.QueueExists("Test"))
        {
            QueueClient client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(strConnectionString, "Test", ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            var qMessage = Console.ReadLine();
            using (MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(qMessage)))
            {
                BrokeredMessage bMsg = new BrokeredMessage(strm);
                bMsg.MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                bMsg.TimeToLive = new TimeSpan(05, 00, 00);
                client.Send(bMsg);
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The receive code:

```
 string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"];
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(strConnectionString);
        if (namespaceManager.QueueExists("Test"))
        {
            QueueClient client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(strConnectionString, "Test",ReceiveMode.PeekLock);
            if (client != null)
            {
                OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions();
                options.AutoComplete = false;
                options.AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(31);                 


                client.OnMessage((message) =>
                    {                           
                        Console.WriteLine(message.State.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Message Id: " + message.MessageId);
                        Stream stream = message.GetBody<Stream>();
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        Console.WriteLine("Message: " + reader.ReadToEnd());                                
                        Console.WriteLine("***************");
                        message.Abandon();
                    });
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

I see that whenever I call **Abandon**, the message is getting DeadLettered. My assumption was that it should get Active and can be picked up by another client.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your understanding of [BrokeredMessage.Abandon Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.abandon.aspx) is correct. It is intended to abandon the peek-lock acquired on the message (but **NOT** abandon the message itself) and hence, makes it available for other receivers to pick the Message up.

### Here's how we envisioned different states of a peek-lock'ed message:

**Basics first**

**The 'Why'**: If Customers need Competing-Consumer (Job-Queue) semantics - where they need multiple workers to simultaneously process different messages from a Queue with **Exactly-Once** guarantee - then they use the ReceiveMode.PeekLock. In this model, each worker (the queue receiver) needs a way to communicate the Progress of its Current message (Job) to other workers. Hence, brokeredMessage provides **4 functions** to express the states.

**The 'What'**:

- if a message is successfully processed by the current Worker - call [BrokeredMessage.Complete()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.complete.aspx)
- if the BrokeredMessage cannot be processed by the current worker, and want the processing to be retried on another Worker - then, **Abandon the message**. But, the catch here is: lets say, there are 2 workers and each of them thinks that the other one can process this message and calls Abandon - soon they will end up in an Infinite loop of retry'ing to process just that message! So, to avoid this situation, we provided a Configuration called [MaxDeliveryCount on QueueDescription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription.maxdeliverycount.aspx). This setting guards the limit on the number of times the message is delivered from the Queue to receiver. **In the above example, Each time you received (and abandoned) the message, the 'deliveryCount' on the ServiceBus service is incremented. When it reaches 10 - the message has hit max no. of deliveries and hence, will be deadlettered.**
- if the current receiver (worker) knows for sure, that, this message cannot be processed, **[BrokeredMessage.DeadLetter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.deadletter.aspx)**. The goal here is to let the consuming application Audit the dead-lettered messages regularly.
- if the current receiver (worker) cannot process this message, but, knows that this message can be processed at a later point of time [BrokeredMessage.Defer()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.defer.aspx).

HTH!
Sree

Comment: Very thorough description of dead letter and abandon. Thanks